# Creating Springboot image with Docker took box on windows 10 using spotify maven plugin

Tags: maven, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, docker-toolbox

I use docker tool box in my windows 10 home laptop. Trying to create a docker image using the springboot project I have been working on. Followed the tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Have been struggling with the error for past three days

```
Apr 03, 2019 11:52:57 AM com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://192.168.99.100:2376: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46.027 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-03T11:52:57+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 63M/433M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.9:build (default-cli) on project IssueTracker: Could not build image: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity: Connection reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
```

Many websites I look up said this could be something related to disabling TLS. I tried to expose the host, disable the tls but still the issue persists. Any help will be appreciated.

The following is my maven plugin config

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
        <configuration>
            <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you sure your Docker daemon and its socket is running? What happens if you execute a command like `docker ps` on the command line?

Comment: Docker ps is running. but docker ps is not returning empty. Docker version is returning version through.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run this maven goal inside "Docker Quickstart Terminal"?

Comment: Yes. I did. The result was the same.